# HTML Select Align Right > Option Align Left

Tags: html, css

Hi I need to align my select/dropdown in HTML.

The result needs to be right aligned (see 1st result select of the fiddle). But during the selection process I would prefer for it to be left aligned (see dropdown event of the 2nd select of the fiddle). Is there a way of doing this? It's easier for the eyes :)

I tried this code but it doesnt work

```
select {
    direction: rtl;
}
select option {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ywv2c6mk/

Result - [http://i.imgur.com/40BiBfY.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5sti.png) (no need to float the selection on the right)

Comment: Doesnt seem like there's an answer for this. Different browsers, different ways of interpreting the data.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you

code:

```
  .select{
    text-align:right;
}
.select > option {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/srg261/74qhs0ua/)

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
/*for Selects*/
 select {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}
.select option {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/g93659v5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check this CSS

```
/*for Selects*/
 .select {
    direction: rtl;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    text-align: right;
}
.select option {
    direction: ltr;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
```